# FPDF error: Could not include font metric file, but file exists

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm getting this error in a website I've taken over from someone else:

```
FPDF error: Could not include font metric file
```

I have the path to the folder defined with:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','xxxxx');
```

I have looked at other answers on Stackoverflow, which suggest that this means the folder or file do not exist. But in this case they do (I'm able to point at them with the web browser).

I would like to include a link here but would rather not for security reasons, unless anyone knows a safe way of doing so?

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
G

Comment: does `xxxxx` is a relative or absolute path to script?

Comment: When I received the site it was a relative path (starting: "/var/www/vhosts/"). This produced the error: "open_basedir restriction in effect.". So I changed it to an absolute path. This removed that error, but left the "Could not include font metric file" error.

Comment: maybe the path is not ok. try to make it relative `../../fontdir`

Comment: `/var/www/vhosts` indicates that it was an absolute path. Most likely your path is wrong.

Comment: True, it was an absolute path, sorry. And I have since changed it to http://www.xxxxx.com/path/to/font. Which I know is still an absolute path, but I know that it is correct and that a font is there. Still not working though!

Comment: Ok I changed the path (to something like "/var/www/vhosts/") -- similar to what it was originally, but I think the original code just had the wrong domain name. Thanks for all your feedback! As you said, clentfort, the path was wrong. If there's any way to mark your response as an answer I will do, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

The cause turned out te be the fact that I copied the fonts code from Notepad into a manually created php file (for instance manually created helvetica.php).

After a while I decided to explicitly import the files (eclipse->file->import). After that the error disappeared. It was probably a permissions problem.

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding in the php font file, (example: `opensans-regular.php`), the following line at the bottom:

```
$fpdf_charwidths['opensans-regular']=$cw;
```